# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10) on Core Data Fetch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an intermittent bug that is proving very hard to debug.

I'm getting the following error from the following method

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10) on Core Data Fetch

```
class func getAll(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Tag] {
    var returnValue: [Tag] = []
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Tag.entityName())
        returnValue = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Tag]
    } catch {
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

The bug is extermely intermittent, and is only happening on every few 100 sessions, but is appearing frequent enough that I need to deal with it. The code breaks on the line `returnvalue = try context.execute...`

- From debugging, my `fetchRequest` is not `nil`
- my `context` is not `nil`
- returnValue has a default value of an empty array
- my backgroundContext is running on a background thread

I've turned on the NSZombieFlag to try to see if some memory is deallocated somewhere and then being accessed, but I'm stumped on what is causing this. Any ideas or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the catch statement you should print out the error, which may guide you in the right direction. Could you do this and then put the error message in your question? Also, I may be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure NSFetchRequest requires that you provide an NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: The catch block is never reached, if it was reached, the crash wouldn't occur. I added the error statement in the catch block, but it still never reaches it. The catch block is there to prevent a core data fetch error, not a bad access error.

Comment: As for the sort descriptor being required. Its definitely not. Per Apple's documentation "A value of nil is treated as no sort descriptors" and that is the default value when you do not provide one.

Answer (score 10):

Almost all **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** issues I've seen with Core Data are caused by trying to use thread concurrency instead of the newer queue concurrency model.

Since iOS 5 you are required to use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` when accessing a managed object context.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Comment: I have no choice but to use Core Data and multi-threading. I'm using the following syntax. privateContext.performBlock {}

Comment: If your issue is with `CoreData`'s `NSMAnagedContext.save()`method. I recommend **saving the context from within the perform block**, to make sure all data needed by CoreData will be still available